# ssh-keygen error: Passphrase is too short

Tags: hadoop, ssh

I was trying to install hadoop on my system in which I need to configure SSH to access to localhost. But while generating the keygen using the command

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -P --

But while generating this keygen I got the following error

```
anamika@Alex:/home/alex$ cd
anamika@Alex:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P --
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/anamika/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/home/anamika/.ssh'.
Saving key "/home/anamika/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: passphrase is too short(minimum five characters)
anamika@Alex:~$ exit
alex@Alex:~$
```

What is passphrase here? Also I tried to give some file name to save the key but still it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are mistakenly writing hyphen in place of double quotes in the second line:

> anamika@Alex:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P --

replace the above with the following

> anamika@Alex:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""